# Compute intersection points of n circles

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ circles in the plane. I need to describe a algorithm which computes
all the intersection points of the circles. The algorithm should run in $O((n + k)\log n)$ time,
where $k$ is the number of intersection points.

I was thinking about some sort of a variant to the bentley ottmann algorithm to count the intersections of $n$ segments, But this never got me anywhere.

Ive seen this topic:
[Circle Intersection with Sweep Line Algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/circle-intersection-with-sweep-line-algorithm)
But the "Swap" Part is missing here.

Any help will be very appericiated :)

Comment: It is not clear whether an 'intersection' is an intersection point that all circles of $S$ pass through, or if an intersection point is just a point that is common to two circles from the set $S$. And I assume you don't mean the region of intersection in common of two circles (like a Venn diagram) but just the intersection of the boundaries of the circles. It might help to define your circles, perhaps as the set of points at distance away from (x,y) and their representation, probably as some triplet (x,y,r)

Comment: Adapting Bentley-Ottman seems reasonable.  Divide each circle up into four quarters, so each arc covers 90 degrees of the circle.  Can you take it from there?  If you understand Bentley-Ottman it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @D.W. I will try that, Thank you.